# Over Ride Root Dir .htaccess With Sub Dir .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know this seem's like a common question, however all answers involve modification of the Root directory .htaccess.

There is a .htacccess within the root directory, of which redirects all requests to a single php file. In the directory I have another dir, which I require direct access too.
Obviously, the root .htaccess prevents this, **what** would I need in the sub dir .htaccess to implement this?

I cannot modify the existing root dir .htaccess

**Tried**, to no avail:

using `RewriteEngine Off`
using `RewriteRule ^$ index.php$1` (with engine turned on of course)

...

Comment: htaccess files in subdirectories have precedence over htaccess files in parent directories

Comment: "what would I need in the sub dir .htaccess to implement this?"

I've tried a rewrite rule that points all requests to the sub dir index file, but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your sub-directory create a new .htaccess with this line:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
```

**This will automatically override any directive you may have used in root .htaccess when request contains this sub-directory**

Comment: i was silly & was using the wrong user account. thanks all the same :)